# Swift guarding weak self for nested callbacks

Tags: swift, callback

My question is more like better practice for the answer. 
Say we have multiple nested layers of callbacks, each layer we have to make `self` to be `weak` and I know we can write `guard` for each layer (see code snippet 1), but is this even necessary? If we only guard at the first layer should it be enough (see code snippet 2)?

If we think from the stand point of reference counting, will the first `strongself` be good enough?

Snippet 1:

```
let callBack1 = { [weak self] xx in 
  guard let strongSelf = self { return }
  // strongSelf.func(param)

  let callBack2 = { [weak self] yy in {
    guard let strongSelf = self { return }
    // strongSelf.func(param)

    let callBack3 = { [weak self] zz in
      guard let strongSelf = self { return }
      // strongSelf.func(param)
    }
  }
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
let callBack1 = { [weak self] xx in 
  guard let strongSelf = self { return }
  // strongSelf.func(param)

  let callBack2 = { [weak self] yy in {
    // strongSelf.func(param)

    let callBack3 = { [weak self] zz in
      // strongSelf.func(param) 
    }
  }
}
```

Note: This is a legit case in our code base, don't assume this will never happen.

---

Edit: To clarify the question, we assume each callback is happening asynchronously, and the `self` here is reference the current class (maybe a model, maybe a view controller) that can be release / pop during the any of the three call backs happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think most part in @Andriy's answer is correct. But the most correct answer is that we don't even need to put `[weak self]` in any nested blocks.

When I first heard this from my colleagues, I don't want to buy it. But the truth is that, the first block defines the **captured** `self` to be `weak` and this captured self will be affecting all the captured self within current scope, in other words, within first block's `{}`. Therefore, there is no need to apply `[weak self]` any more if we have done it in the first most layer of callback.

It is very hard to find the exact document from Apple to prove this but the following code snippet with core foundation retain count `CFGetRetainCount()` it can prove that's true.

```
class TestClass {
    var name = ""
    var block1: (()->Void)?
    var block2: (()->Void)?

    func test() {
        print(CFGetRetainCount(self))
        self.block1 = { [weak self] in
            self?.block2 = { // [weak self] in
                print(CFGetRetainCount(self))
            }
            self?.block2?()
            print(CFGetRetainCount(self))
        }
        self.block1?()
        print(CFGetRetainCount(self))
    }

    deinit {
        print(CFGetRetainCount(self))
    }
}

do {
    let tstClass = TestClass()
    print(CFGetRetainCount(tstClass))
    tstClass.test()
    print(CFGetRetainCount(tstClass))
}
```

If you are interested, you can try this in your playground, feel free to remove the comment for the `[weak self]` for block2, you will see the same answer.

Retain count is always 2 and `deinit` is called correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you capture `strongSelf` once it will be available in nested closures. However, this means that your object will not be deallocated. It may be good in some cases and bad in other ones. For example, consider that you call these nested closures from a view controller which lets people search for a city and pull a list of restaurants available in them and for the sake of the example let's assume that this is done with 2 nested asynchronous requests.

The first callback is called and `self` is captured. Now it will be retained until the second callback is called. But what if a user exits from your search controller? Do you want to prevent its deallocation because it is waiting for your second callback?

Basically, you just need to decide whether you want to capture your object between callbacks or not. If not, here is another possible alternative syntax which may be useful:

`self?.someMethod()`

Comment: How can self become nil while there’s a strong reference in callBack1 to it? Since the strong reference is used inside callback2 and 3 it won’t die until all those are finished no?

Comment: @Purpose if the callbacks are used for asynchronous requests then `self` becomes nil easily. Consider this - prior to callbac1 self is not nil. Yet in the body of the callback it may be nil. The same is true for the transition from the body of callback1 to the body of callback2.

Comment: [See for yourself.](https://gist.github.com/Limdi/10ec34c639380dde2dc093bfaf689701) I don't know whether in the line of callback2 the two '{' are there on purpose, but I wasn't able to compile it with it so I removed the right one.

Comment: @Purpose I did not say "it definitely becomes nil". Create another example when this logic is called from some view controller. Initiate an asynchronous request which calls callback 10 seconds later. And in the meantime exit from the current view controller. Your strongSelf will be nil in this case

Comment: `I did not say “it definitely becomes nil“`. Then why would self become nil after strongSelf got captured in your case while it did not in mine? Would a closure suddenly not capture strongSelf anymore? And if the closures were to capture strongSelf, how could self become nil and strongSelf.a = 3, 4 still be valid?

Comment: @Purpose actually you are right. If we capture strongSelf it will be available in all nested closures. However, there still may be one pitfall. I'll update my answer

Comment: A good point to not to do searches in a viewController. Thank you for not locking up after I contradicted you, that happens sometimes.

Comment: @Purpose thank you for spotting an error in my reasoning :) Regarding searches - it is actually fine to do them in a view controller. After all, if your view controller is gone and there is no place to present your search results – what is the point of all those nested callbacks? :)

Comment: A good point. So a more likely scenario would that if the first call got through which modifies sth, don’t allow deallocation or the app gets in an invalid state but allow the post to never arrive.